# showing a percentage number for two variables in c#

Tags: c#, html, sharepoint

I have two variables, I want to showing as percentage, when I calculate them with operator the result is 0 why?
please help me. Thanks
this is my source

```
  int count = (from a in dc.jawabans
                         where a.q14 == "5 : Sangat Baik/ Sangat Puas"
                         select a).Count();
            TextBox1.Text = count.ToString();

            int total = (from b in dc.jawabans
                         where b.q14 != ""
                         select b).Count();

            TextBox2.Text = total.ToString();

            int persen = (count / total) * 100;

            TextBox3.Text = persen.ToString();
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7pFP.png)

Answer (score 2):

`count` is `int`, `total` is `int` too. In C# when `int` divided by `int` the result is `int`. The solution is to cast one variable as `double`.

```
int persen = (int)((double)count / total * 100);
```

Comment: This code is not compiling.

Comment: @mybirthname Thanks for reminder.

Comment: @mybirthname It should compile now. Already tested it. :)

Comment: Yes after the edit you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this:

```
decimal persen = (count / (decimal)total) * 100;
```

After that you can round it if you want:

```
TextBox3.Text = Math.Round(persen, 2).ToString();
```

Division of 2 integers is an integer, so you should specified that one of them is decimal.

Comment: Do you really need to use `decimal` for something that you're going to display to 2 decimal places?

Comment: @MatthewWatson what is your suggestion and why I should not use decimal ?

Comment: Well a `decimal` isn't a build-in intrinsic - it's a struct, and calculations with it are many times slower than using `double` (calculations with which are generally performed in hardware on the processor). `decimal` is intended for calculations - particularly financial calculations - where you need a very high precision. Otherwise, just use `double`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson double is also a struct and we don't have background information. This could be currency field which can be reused and really for dividing two numbers you will not have the biggest performance boost. So for current case doesn't matter.

Comment: @mybirthname Generally, processor has special hardware to do `double` computation. `decimal` is not "native" and processor does not have hardware to do the computation.

Comment: @mybirthname A double is nominally a struct, but as I said it's also a built-in intrinsic for which the processor has native support. Therefore you should always use a `double` instead of a `decimal` unless there is a specific reason not to. (It's similar to using `int` instead of `BigInteger`.)

Answer (score 0):

Because you dividing two integers, so the result will be integer as well. You can set count and total as double , then you will get correct result.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the sum you are doing is with ints, so the value is rounded to the nearest whole number - for example if `count` is 20, and `total` is 100

```
int persen = (count / total) * 100;
```

is the same as doing

```
int persen = (count / total); //this = 0 as it would evaluate to 0.2 => 0
persen = persen * 100; //still 0
```

Whereas

```
int persen = ((double)count / (double)total) * 100;
//This would be 20, as count and total are both cast to a double - it also works if you only cast one of them
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal persen = (count / (decimal)total) * 100; //count 20, total 100, so person will be 0 if it is int in your code
```

If you devide int by int, it will give you int not double.
So either convert count or total as decimal or double according to your requirement.